# Embedding PhoneGap WebView into Xamarin

Tags: cordova, xamarin

We have some PhoneGap WebViews which we want to embed in a Xamarin app. We found the documentation from Scott Blomquist (http://scott.blomqui.st/2012/08/embedding-cordova-phonegap-in-monotouch-apps/ ) about how to achieve this. 
Has anyone successfully embedded a newer version of Cordova?

Answer (score 0):

This developer did it in 2014 with Cordova 3.7.0, and we've also done it at http://www.appazur.com (not yet published).

http://sviluppomobile.blogspot.com/2014/10/using-cordovaphonegap-with-xamarin.html